# Problem with installing URL Rewrite 2.1 using Web Platform Installer 5.1 On Windows Serve 2016

Tags: iis-10

I am having problems with installing this product.

Here is my log file:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://aka.ms/webpifeed51
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://aka.ms/webpifeed51 responded with 301
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://webpifeed.blob.core.windows.net/webpifeed/5.1/WebProductList.xml
Server: Kestrel
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:9b037ab9-fa5a-4c09-81bd-41ffa859f01e
X-Response-Cache-Status: True
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
Expires: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 11:55:54 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 11:55:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
```

I could not give the full detail of this log file. Because of text limitation of this site. But my problem is same to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97661ed7-9e94-46e8-8230-a363e14d1d3e/problem-with-installing-url-rewrite-21-using-web-platform-installer-51?forum=iiswebplatforminstaller).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed Web Platform Installer is dying so don't waste time on it.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi for giving a link about the Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved with direction installation of rewrite exe. I downloaded it from [https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads] & scrolling below then select x64 installer. It has been installed successfully without any error. When I reset my IIS then **UrlRewrite** has appeared. I would be thankful if any one give me any suggestion about this issue.